# zooming content inside div using transform scale property

Tags: css, zooming, transform, scaletransform

I am trying to zoom contents of div(same behavior as browser zoom). After searching a lot I found css 3 transform scale property will full fill this requirement.
The content is zooming when I increase the scale size but I am losing the contents of the div. overflow: hidden also didn't help.

```
var currentZoom = 1.0;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btn_ZoomIn').click(
        function () {
            currentZoom = currentZoom+0.04;
            var scaleString = "scale("+currentZoom+")";
            $('#divName').css("transform", scaleString);
        })
    $('#btn_ZoomOut').click(
        function () {
            //var scaleString = "scale("+currentZoom -= .1+")";
            currentZoom = currentZoom-0.04;
            var scaleString = "scale("+currentZoom+")";
            $('#divName').css("transform", scaleString);
        })

});
```

Js fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/chaitut715/k4WsB/

Answer (score 2):

Add a container around `#divName`:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="divName">
        <img src="https://www.google.co.in/intl/en_ALL/images/srpr/logo11w.png"></img>
    </div>
</div>
```

And set `overflow: hidden;` on the new container:

```
.wrapper {
    overflow: hidden; /* 'auto' would probably be better */
    width: 500px;
}
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k4WsB/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your answer preserving the buttons after zoom. But the content inside div is disappearing after zoom.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve. Do you want the contents of `#myDiv` to be scrollable? or always fully visible?

Comment: Yes, I want contents of #myDiv to be scrollable. Sorry for not explaining clearly.

Comment: OK. Then change `overflow: hidden;` to `overflow: auto;` http://jsfiddle.net/k4WsB/2/

Comment: In the above link, scroll is coming but I can see some part of Image only after zooming.

Comment: Attached screeshot: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5Gli6_pmDb3OGdDMWo4NGpyc2M/edit?usp=sharing